Why does Peter believe that Lyla has his location wrong?
While he is motivating Miles, Lyla is speaking to Peter on comms:

LYLA: We got your location Peter. Sit tight, we’re on the way.
PETER: Wait wait, no no no! You don’t have my location, over!

Peter means that Lyla and her team do not accurately know or have  the
correct information about his current whereabouts.
Why does Peter believe that Lyla has his location wrong?

This seems more like an English language question.
But Peter at that time is trying to help Miles who is hiding from the Spider-Society. When Layla (a member of that organization) says he has Peter's location (And also Miles location by extent) this makes Miles believe Peter sold him out.
So Peter is franticly trying to dismiss Layla's claim in the hopes of:

A: that she and the rest of the Spider-Society don't go towards them.
B: trying to convince Miles he did not betray him.

